# Не работает UNIQUE в sqlite3

Tags: база-данных, sqlite3, sqlite

Создаю таблицу и указываю какие значения должны быть уникальны, но бд спокойно вставляет одинаковые записи дальше.Создаю таблицу так:

```
int createOperatorTable(){

    printf("Create OPERATOR table... \n");

    dbOpenResult = openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
    char *sql = sqlite3_mprintf(
             "CREATE TABLE %q (" \
             " %q  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" \
             ", %q  TEXT  NOT NULL UNIQUE" \
             ", %q  TEXT  NOT NULL" \
             ", %q  TEXT  NOT NULL" \
             ", %q  TEXT  NOT NULL);" \
            , TABLE_OPERATOR_NAME 
            , SCHEME_OPERATOR_ID
            , SCHEME_OPERATOR_FULL_NAME
            , SCHEME_OPERATOR_ACCESS
            , SCHEME_OPERATOR_LOGIN
            , SCHEME_OPERATOR_PASSWORD);

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    checkTransaction(rc);
    closeDatabase();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсмотрел решение в sql:

```
int createOperatorTable(){

    printf("Create OPERATOR table... \n");

    dbOpenResult = openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
    char *sql = sqlite3_mprintf(
             "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %q (" \
             " %q  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" \
             ", %q  TEXT  NOT NULL" \
             ", %q  TEXT  NOT NULL" \
             ", %q  TEXT  NOT NULL" \
             ", %q  TEXT  NOT NULL" \
             ", UNIQUE (%q) ON CONFLICT FAIL);" \
            , TABLE_OPERATOR_NAME
            , SCHEME_OPERATOR_ID
            , SCHEME_OPERATOR_FULL_NAME
            , SCHEME_OPERATOR_ACCESS
            , SCHEME_OPERATOR_LOGIN
            , SCHEME_OPERATOR_PASSWORD
            , SCHEME_OPERATOR_FULL_NAME);

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    checkTransaction(rc);
    closeDatabase();
    return 0;
}
```

Но не понимаю почему первый вариант, который указывается в разных туториалах не работает.